# Python Sockets Error: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python, sockets

I have a very simple server written in Python that accepts connections from multiple clients. When I use nmap to scan localhost (`nmap -p0- localhost`), my server crashes with an `OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected` error on `client, port = ready_socket.getpeername()`. I suspect this is because nmap is sending an RST packet instead of the ACK packet in the three-way handshake. I'm not sure how to detect and handle this correctly.

I tried to look in the Python documentation for something like `socket.is_connected()` to handle this case, but I could not find anything. Here is the code for the server:

```py
import sys
import socket
import select

def run_server(port):
    listening_socket = socket.socket()
    listening_socket.bind(("", port))
    listening_socket.listen()

    active_sockets = set()
    active_sockets.add(listening_socket)

    while True:
        ready_sockets, _, _ = select.select(active_sockets, {}, {})
        for ready_socket in ready_sockets:

            if ready_socket == listening_socket:
                connected_socket, (client, port) = ready_socket.accept()
                active_sockets.add(connected_socket)
                print(f"({client}, {port}): connected")

            else:
                client, port = ready_socket.getpeername()
                received_bytes = ready_socket.recv(4096)
                received_size  = len(received_bytes)

                if received_size == 0:
                    active_sockets.remove(ready_socket)
                    print(f"({client}, {port}): disconnected")
                else:
                    print(f"({client}, {port}) {received_size} bytes: {received_bytes}")


def usage():
    print("usage: select_server.py port", file=sys.stderr)

def main(argv):
    try:
        port = int(argv[1])
    except:
        usage()
        return 1

    run_server(port)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

You can run `python3 server.py 21123` to make the server listen on port 21123.

Answer (score -1):

sorry for that i dont know any about network programming
but maybe your problem occurs by this line:
listening_socket.bind(("", port))
you should consider binding the server socket to a specific IP address associated with the network interface you want the server to listen on